# Similar tools like Facebuilder for blender 2.79

Tags: modeling

I'm using blender 2.79, I can't use 2.8 due to go problem.  I wanna make face model from image by using facebuilder by keen tools but it can't be used in 2.79..

can be anybody help me alternative way to model human face by picture? or how to solve gl problem n then install 2.8 blender? please guys.. ..